# Is it a theorem of first order logic that $\exists x \forall y \alpha(x, y) \implies \exists x \alpha(x, x)$?

Tags: first-order-logic

Here $\alpha(x, y)$ is a well formed formula of first order logic with quantifiers, and $\alpha(x, x)$ is the same formula with all free instances of $y$ replaced by $x$, assuming no variables become bound in $\alpha$ in the process.

I initially thought it is, but it is conspicuously absent from my list of axioms (which features $\forall x \forall y \alpha(x, y) \implies \forall x \alpha(x, x)$ and its dual $\exists x \alpha(x, x) \implies \exists x \exists y \alpha(x, y)$ as the only rules for variable substitution. The only rule of inference is modus ponens.) Trying to prove it in my system is like banging my head against a wall. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: It is indeed a theorem of FOL, but exactly how to derive it in your system will depend on the details of that system (and for that matter it's possible that the system you're using isn't actually complete). The key will be instantiation/generalization rules.

Comment: It's worth to note the order of quantifiers in your title is important here, it's *not* a theorem for $\forall y \exists x \alpha(x, y) \implies \exists x \alpha(x, x)$. Your title wff is a theorem is due to some strong universal property... You can easily find a counterexample for my above proposed claim.